# Child list element still get re-rendered when using unique key id in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

If I understand correctly, if a unique key is provided to each list item, whenever we add new or delete existing items, the remaining ones will be re-rendered. However, I am using a unique key for the **Item** element and when I click the **Add** button, I am still seeing the **render** string (I added a console.log() in the **Item** component) been printed in console X number of times (x equals the number of total list items).

The complete code is as below:

```js
import "./styles.css";

import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid";
import { useState } from "react";

const data = () => {
  let result = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    result.push({
      id: uuidv4(),
      value: i + 1
    });
  }
  return result;
};

function Item({ item }) {
  console.log("render");
  return (
    <li>
      <label>{item.value}</label>
    </li>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState(data());

  function handleAdd(e) {
    setState([
      ...state,
      {
        id: uuidv4(),
        value: state[state.length - 1].value + 1
      }
    ]);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={handleAdd}>Add</button>
      {state.map((item) => (
        <Item item={item} key={item.id} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

CodeSandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-list-with-unique-key-1rxlhx?file=/src/App.js:0-802

Did I miss anything here?

Comment: what are you trying to do? It is adding an item as expected. You need to add a unique key to help react keep track of the list

Comment: @PaulFitzgerald I already added the unique key for the **Item** component. The problem is that: after adding a new list item, the existing ones all get called (console.log("render")).

Comment: yeah that is expected, you have updated the state of `App` so the map gets called again, hence each of the list items console.log being called. You have misunderstood that giving a key doesn't cause a re-render

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keys don't prevent children from re-rendering - rather, they [allow for more efficient "reconciliation"](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html#keys), by changing only the underlying DOM node that matches that key when needed. The child will still re-render in React regardless, but if the rendering of the child results in different markup, the key will be used to efficiently determine which DOM element(s) corresponding to that key needs to be changed, rather than changing *everything*.

If you want to prevent re-rendering, that requires a different tool - `React.memo` often works for individual components. For dynamic lists like these though, you can put the component into state.

```js
const { useState } = React;
const data = () => {
  let result = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    result.push({
      id: Math.random(),
      value: i + 1
    });
  }
  return result;
};

function Item({ item }) {
  console.log("render");
  return (
    <li>
      <label>{item.value}</label>
    </li>
  );
}

function App() {
  const [items, setItems] = useState(() => data().map(dataObj => <Item item={dataObj} />));
  function handleAdd(e) {
    setItems([
      ...items,
      <Item item={{
        id: Math.random(),
        value: items.length + 1
      }} />
    ]);
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={handleAdd}>Add</button>
      {items}
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```